# Increase Mysql Auto Increment Value

Tags: mysql

How can my InnoDB table increment 5 instead 1 in each entry ID?

Thanks

```
ID - TITLE
5  - Entry 1
10 - Entry 2
15 - Entra 3
```

Comment: then don't make **ID** column `auto_increment`. and set the value while you insert.

Comment: u might have deleted some old value ..due to possible relations of id with other tables .mysql dosent reorder the id on delete of any row.

Comment: [See here for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313229/mysql-auto-increment-by-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a TRIGGER on the table?  Something similar to this code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_increaseByFive AFTER INSERT ON tbl
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl SET id = (id - 1) + 5 WHERE title = NEW.title;
  END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html
You should be able to set the amount to increment with an equals sign.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: This does not do what OP asked. See older answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by