# mysql - auto-increment (how to auto-increment by 5)

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql auto_increment by 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313229/mysql-auto-increment-by-5)

I have a table that will have a column that needs to have a primary key. I want to set it to auto-increment, but it should increment by 5 or 10. I have been searching it, but it is hard to find the resource.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with this.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` are merely meant to be unique values per table, not to maintain a specific order. Deleted rows leave holes in the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a server configuration setting called [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment). Note however that this will be for *all* tables.

Comment: is there a way to make it specific to a certain table?