# create a new table with auto_increment of 10 each time

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

[image]how do you create a table with an auto_increment_increment of 10 instead of the default of 1

I am using mySQL and mySQL workbench as well.

After creating the table either with the workbench gui or by statements, I have tried this in workbench and it works only when I add a new record from the workbench but not thru my web app. If I use the web app it starts to auto increment by one again...I just want to create the table and set its increment to 10 every time so first item is 10 then second is 20 then 30 and so on.

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='items';
SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide output of the below
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql auto\_increment by 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313229/mysql-auto-increment-by-5)

Comment: Hi yes will do that ...will edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the `auto_increment_increment=10` globally. The `SET` command you show only sets it for the current session.

Setting it globally makes it affect *every* table, not just your `items` table.

There's no support in MySQL for changing the increment size to a different value for each table.

---

You can change a global option in MySQL with `SET GLOBAL`. To make the change persist when the MySQL server is restarted, you must edit the options file. Read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-system-variables.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

Comment: It would be fine globally for every table but how do you go about doing that?