# Mysql : How can i set number of gap 5 on each increment number in auto increment column?

Tags: mysql

I need to set each increment id +5 from the previous one generated id table wise. It means each auto-increment have to 5 number of the gap. Like this series 2,7,12,17 etc..

Any idea please share.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;`

Comment: it's not working. I have tried that.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313229/mysql-auto-increment-by-5

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes its work but I need to apply to one table only. These changes is applied to whole database.

Comment: create the sequences CREATE SEQUENCE seq MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 5 CACHE 10; and insert as INSERT INTO table_name(id,xxx,xxx)
VALUES (seq.nextval,'xxx','xxx');

Comment: Use triggers for that column without auto increment

Comment: @Pragadees, This question is tagged 'mysql' but MySQL does not support a CREATE SEQUENCE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset

```
SET @@auto_increment_offset=5;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
CREATE TABLE autoinc2 (col INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: This one change is applied to whole database, is there any way to assign for one table only.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be demanding this requirement from an auto increment column.  The contract of an auto increment column only guarantees that each generated value would be unique.  The values would tend to generally be increasing, but if the counter were reset, and certain earlier records were deleted, there could be a value generated smaller than one which already exists.  Instead, consider maintaining some sort of timestamp column which keeps track of when each record were added to your table.  Then, using `ROW_NUMBER`, it is easy to generate the sequence you expect, e.g.

```
SELECT
    5*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts_column) seq
FROM yourTable;
ORDER BY
    ts_column;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment by 5, you can set `auto_increment_increment=5`.

This will apply to all tables, so you should set it as a session variable, not a global variable. The session variable will only apply to INSERT statements made in your current session, not to other sessions.

Then change the option back to 1 before you INSERT to another table.

There is no feature in MySQL to make the auto_increment_increment option apply permanently and for all sessions, but only for a specific table.